# Is Mac OS X Server 10.6 upgradeable to latest Desktop OS X (without Sever.app)

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade, osx-server

Around 2010, my boss purchased a Mac mini Server with 10.6. (Macmini3, 2.53 GHz Core 2 Duo, 4 GB RAM)

This server was retired last week.

Is the Server License (unlimited client) eligible to upgrade to a new release of OS X (Mavericks or Yosemite) or do I have to buy a new license?

Comment: All I had read by now is, that i have to buy a Mountain Lion Licence in the App-Store and normaly upgrade the system. Am I right? Thanks @user3439894 for edit. English i not my native language.

Comment: As far as licensing is concerned I'd suggest contacting Apple directly.  That said, I would just download the "Install OS X El Capitan.app: from the App Store and create a USB Installer using directions in [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372). Then boot from the installer, wipe the HDD and do a clean install of OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once all the updates have been installed and OS X 10.6.8 is installed the App Store suggest to upgrade to OS X 10.11.6.

Therefore, it plays no role whether it is an OS X servers or a "normal" OS X.
As soon as it is 10.6.8, it is eligible to upgrade.